# how to fetch different data on compare rows of two tables

Tags: mysql, index, join, select

I have two tables in my database, one is user_app table in which user info are stored, table are as:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| apikey       | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| app_id       | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| appidt       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| imei_num     | varchar(32)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| app_version  | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| package_name | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| stamp        | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| sdk_version  | float        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Other table is Ad's table through which i retrieve ad's to user, table name creative are shown as:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| campaign_id  | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type         | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title        | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| iconlink     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| marketlink   | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| app_id       | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| package_name | varchar(200) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now i get all user info in **user_app** table via php scripts, along with package name which identify user application. On other hand, in **creative** table i am create some ad's which is send to user, package name also define here.

Here i am checking user application based on package_name, if package_name match in creative table with user_app, then i retrieve other ad and send to user. I am done with this query:

```
SELECT ua.package_name, c.id as cid, c.title, c.description, c.iconlink, c.marketlink
FROM `user_app` AS ua INNER JOIN `creative` AS c ON ua.package_name <> c.package_name
where ua.imei_num = '30c899b5c0f29dbc95418c4173f6f745'
and c.package_name in (12,13) group by `package_name`
```

Problem is when a user has 5 or more app, he will be get different ad per app, but through this query i am able to retrieve only different one ad which is not similar to user app, but if user has 4 app ad's already then i have to send him different ad's.

Another statement is this query is run on server smoothly but sometime it logged as in mysql-slow query which takes 1-10 seconds, so i have to optimized this query for performance.

I apologize for my explanation if it is incomplete, but i am giving my best.

RolandoMySQLDBA: Can you please again have a look on this query and help me to solve this asap. Any help would be very greatful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT ua.package_name, c.id as cid, c.title, c.description, c.iconlink, c.marketlink
FROM `user_app` AS ua INNER JOIN `creative` AS c
ON ua.package_name <> c.package_name
where ua.imei_num = '30c899b5c0f29dbc95418c4173f6f745'
and c.package_name in (12,13)
group by `package_name`
```

I would like to suggest refactoring the query to retrieve needed rows before doing the JOIN

```
SELECT ua.package_name, c.id as cid, c.title, c.description, c.iconlink, c.marketlink
FROM
(
    SELECT package_name FROM `user_app`
    WHERE imei_num = '30c899b5c0f29dbc95418c4173f6f745'
) AS ua INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM `creative`
    WHERE c.package_name in (12,13)
) AS c
ON ua.package_name <> c.package_name
group by ua.package_name;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I tried, but it gives me same output as previous query, in actual if i write there instead of c.package_name "where id IN (12,13) " means if a user package_name match 12 number id then he get 13 number id, and if a user have 4 packages and i am serving 8 ads, then he get another 4 packages from ad's